# Postman: how to get tests status during test run

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a test collection with hundreds of tests.

I'd like to send the test result as an SMS message on my phone.

I have all the other parts working but is there any way to get a count of passed and failed tests as a variable for my last test which is testing our SMS service, so I could get the result to my phone as an SMS message.

I only need to get a count of failed and count of passed cases during the collection run.

But if it is possible to get the name(s) of the failed cases as well, then I would be fully satisfied.

-Jarno Storhammar-

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a node script with [Newman](https://www.twilio.com/) and sending the results captured in the `summary.run.stats` object to an external API, that would send you an SMS message with the details you want. Services like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) could handle that part.

It's not something the native Postman app would perform out of the box but I'm sure it can be done.